# How to make a multi item carousel from materialize(css) cards when the cards data is provided by a loop?

Tags: javascript, css, django-templates, carousel

The code here generates a list of cards using the for loop. These cards are to be put in a carousel with 4 cards visible each time and a next arrow button brings the next 4 cards. I have used materialize cards.

```
'''
<div class="row">
    {% for course in course_details %}
            <div class="col s3">
                <div class="card medium">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <a href="{{ course.0 }}"><img src="{{ course.0 }}" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <p>{{ course.1 }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-action">
                        <a href="{{ course.1 }}">Price</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    {%endfor%}
    </div>
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this:

1. Create a `carousel-slider`:

   `<div class="carousel carousel-slider"></div>`
2. Create a `carousel-item` for every 4 cards. This is a single slide, and needs also a class of `row` so that we can use the grid on the cards:

   `<div class="carousel-item row"></div>`
3. Place your cards:

`<div class="col s3"><div class="card blue-grey darken-1"></div></div>`

And then initialise:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-slider');
    var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems);   });
```

https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/RwrYBYx